# multi-threading limit?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am writing a program using threads in c++ in linux.

Currently, I am just keeping an array of threads, and every time one second has elapsed, I check to see which have finished, and restart them. Is this bad? I need to keep this program running for a long time. As it is now, I am getting a code 11 after so many loops of restarting threads (the 100th loop in the last trial). I figured that reusing threads and making sure I only have a small number of them running at any one time, that I would not hit the limit.  The array I am using only has a size of 8 (of course, I am not starting 8 each time, just those that have stopped).

Any ideas?

My code is below:

```
if ( loop_times == 0 || pthread_kill(threads[t],0) != 0 ) 
{ 
    rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, thread_stall, (void *)NULL); 
    if (rc){ 
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc); 
        exit(-1); 
    } 
thread_count++; 
}
```

The loop_times variable is just so that I can get into the loop and start the threads the first time. Otherwise, I get a SEGFAULT because the threads haven't been started before.

Also, I have been wanting to see the value of PTHREAD_THREADS_MAX, but I can't print it (even when including limits.h)

Comment: If your program runs for awhile you can use ps -eLf to check how many threads linux thinks you are using.

Comment: If you're using a recent compiler use C++ <thread> instead of pthreads.

Comment: It is a very bad practice to kill threads. Let them finish. Many threading API won't give you this possibility, those who do say it's not a good idea to do so.

Comment: Why should I use thread over pthreads?  I am not killing threads in the above code anywhere, btw.

Comment: I'm confused.  If you want these threads to run continually, why not just wrap the code in the thread in a 'for(;;)' or 'while(1)'?   Why the micro-management?

Comment: I only want 8 to run at a time, and a max of 8 to be started every second... I don't want them to run again as soon as they can, but to wait a bit.  My question isn't so much how to do this, but why what I have dies after a while.

Comment: @Risshuu - you posted some code that you think has a problem, so all I can do is look at what you have posted <g>.  My advice on any thread micro-management code is 'get rid of it if you can', ie. if you can get away with a loop then do so.  IF the threads need to pause for some legitimate reason, put a sleep() in the loop.  If you don't continually create and destroy threads, you will not get a code 11.  Why bother debugging and fixing something if you can just design it away?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't put the information that I thought that I put (nor enough info.. but I didn't want to post all of my code either).  I think that I figured out what was wrong, though.  If I join the thread before restarting it, the problem seems to go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, my problem was that I needed to pthread_join my thread before I restarted it each time.  After this, I stopped getting a code 11 and stopped having "still reachable" memory when running it through Valgrind.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use multiple threads...It better to go for thread pool.
Start a set of threads as detached ones and then through a queue you can send info to every thread so that it can work on that and wait for next input from you.

Comment: There's a non submitted boost library for that (boost.threadpool).

Comment: Further more, creating many threads will probably *decrease* the performance of your application.

Comment: That's why I'm only using a maximum of eight at a time at any given time.  .. maybe I am misunderstanding your comment.

Comment: I have thought about thread pools.. but I also do not want to use the boost library atm, so...